# Summarize aggregations into friendly text

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table in SQL Server :

```
number     grade    weight
--------------------------
1         A         185
2         A         179
3         C         191
4         C         192
5         C         193
6         A         194
7         A         196
8         A         188
9         A         187
10        A         200
11        B         201
12        B         202
13        B         203
14        B         191
15        B         187
```

and I want this output in SQL Server  (return this Text with Query not function):

```
Count of A : 7 , Sum of A : 1329 - Count of B : 5 , Sum of B : 984 - Count of C : 3 , Sum of C : 576
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Then we can help you fix what is not working.

Comment: Please also tag the question with the version of SQL Server you need to support. Solutions can vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Modern Versions

If on SQL Server 2017 or better, you can also do it this way (and this prevents you from having to know in advance and hard-code all the possible grades `A`, `B`, `C` etc., which makes it harder to add `D`, `E`, and so on later):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT g = grade, y = CONCAT('Count$g', COUNT(*), ' , Sum$g', SUM(weight)) 
  FROM dbo.TableName
  GROUP BY grade
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(REPLACE(y,'$g',' of ' + g + ' : '),' - ')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g)
FROM x;
```

Output

> Count of A : 7 , Sum of A : 1329 - Count of B : 5 , Sum of B : 984 - Count of C : 3 , Sum of C : 576

---

## 2012, 2014, 2016

If on 2012 - 2016, you can't use `STRING_AGG()`, but you can use `FOR XML PATH` to achieve the same thing:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT g = grade, y = CONCAT('Count$g', COUNT(*), ' , Sum$g', SUM(weight)) 
  FROM dbo.TableName
  GROUP BY grade
)
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ' - ' + REPLACE(y, '$g', ' of ' + g + ' : ') 
      FROM x 
      ORDER BY g 
      FOR XML PATH(''),
     TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 3, '');
```

---

## 2005, 2008, 2008 R2

If you're on earlier (unsupported and ill-advised) versions (2005 - 2008 R2), you'll just have to make changes to the latter to perform manual string concatenations (and data type handling) instead of using `CONCAT()`.

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT g = grade, y = 'Count$g'  + CONVERT(varchar(11), COUNT(*))
                      + ' , Sum$g' + CONVERT(varchar(11), SUM(weight)) 
  FROM dbo.TableName
  GROUP BY grade
)
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ' - ' + REPLACE(y, '$g', ' of ' + g + ' : ') 
      FROM x 
      ORDER BY g 
      FOR XML PATH(''),
    TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 3, '');
```

---

## Examples

[Working dbfiddle using a table variable](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc0b38985a4accb70f76ace0e3d35379)

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron Bertrand , Of course must CAST()  g to varchar

Comment: @MohammadHadiShabanpour Could you be more specific? `g = grade`, `grade = 'A', 'B', 'C', etc.`, why do you need to cast? Could you show a fiddle where not casting breaks something?

Answer (score 3):

```
;with flat_cte as (
    select
      sum(iif(grade='A', 1, 0)) CountA,
      sum(iif(grade='A', weight, 0)) SumA,
      sum(iif(grade='B', 1, 0)) CountB,
      sum(iif(grade='B', weight, 0)) SumB,
      sum(iif(grade='C', 1, 0)) CountC,
      sum(iif(grade='C', weight, 0)) SumB
    from
      MyTable)
select
   (concat('[Count of A : ]', cast(CountA as varchar(9)), ' , ',
           '[Sum of A : ]', cast(SumA as varchar(9)), ' - ',
           '[Count of B : ]', cast(CountB as varchar(9)), ' , ',
           '[Sum of B : ]', cast(SumB as varchar(9)), ' - ',
           '[Count of C : ]', cast(CountC as varchar(9)), ' , ',
           '[Sum of C : ]', cast(SumC as varchar(9)))
from flat_cte;
```